# EFCore with SQLite shows concurrency exception

Tags: .net, sqlite, entity-framework-core, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

I am using EFCore in .Net Core project with db as SQLite. When i try to **add** a row to a table I am getting
"Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s). Data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. unit of work"

When I change from SQLite to SQLServer, everything works fine.

My entity has an ID property which is the Primary Key. I tried adding [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] attribute and without it. Still getting same error.  But when i tried by entering the Id value along with rest of data, the insertion works.
Could someone throw some light into this issue. Why am i getting this error only for SQLite.

Comment: pls, show what you have tried and where is the error

Comment: Sorry, couldnt add the code. Infact i found the issue. I had a property called RowId in my entity which conflicted with the default RowId of Sqlite. I renamed this property and was able to add values to the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The entity had a user-defined property called RowId which conflicted with the default RowId of SQLite. I renamed this user-defined property and I was able to resolve this issue.